# Display the data that does not exist in particular table using multiple interconnecting table join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to list all students that did not enroll in this subject yet using the var_subjectcode as filter. I am using the code below but it is not working properly. It keeps on resulting empty string.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_enrollment//
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_enrollment(IN var_subjectcode VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
Select CONCAT(a.LastName, ', ', a.FirstName) as StudentNames , a.number
From a
Join b ON a.number = b.number
Join c ON b.number = c.number
Join d ON c.stud_id = d.stud_id
Join e ON d.subject_code = e.subject_code
Where e.subjectcode = var_subjectcode AND a.number is NULL;
END
//DELIMITER ;
```

If I excluded the `AND a.number is NULL` in the whole query it returns the list of students who enrolled in that particular ***var_subjectcode***. What I wanted is the opposite. If I put value in the var_subjectcode it should return the list of students who are not enrolled in that ***var_subjectcode***.

*var_subjectcode* is in the **E Table**.

Is there a better way to get my desired result?

Comment: Which table is var_subjectcode in?
Please also provide some sample data.

Comment: What does 'not working properly.' - mean? Please provide sample data an expected outcome as text in the question or to a fiddle.

Comment: `AND a.number is NULL` selects only rows where this column is NULL - but for these rows `Join b ON a.number = b.number` gives empty rowset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want list of student who not participated in the given subject code, here is qhat you need also simplified:

```
Select CONCAT(a.LastName, ', ', a.FirstName) as StudentNames , a.number
From a
Join b ON a.number = b.number
Join c ON b.number = c.number

Join d ON c.stud_id = d.stud_id
where not exists ( select 1 from d where c.stud_id = d.stud_id and d.subject_code =var_subjectcode  )
```

Comment: Thanks! This one fix my issue!